# vb.net Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type on Enum

Tags: vb.net

I've had to update a vb.net project from .NetFramework 4 to .NetFramework 4.7.2. In the process the following code is now throwing an error

```
Dim actuatorModelsArr = DirectCast(retNumberList, Array) Dim
Dim actuatorModels = actuatorModelsArr.Cast(Of ACTUATORMODELS)().ToList()
```

The error is `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.`

retNumberList is an Integer array
ACTUATORMODELS is an Enum

in the .netFramework 4 version actuatorModels is a list of the Enum
{System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FisherIECLib.ACTUATORMODELS]}

The list is used later in the module via linq to grab one of the Enums as a return value.

Is there a way around this or a way to create a list of the Enum?

Thanks in advance,
Hank

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing the error issue from inside the call chain of `ToList`, more specifically in the `List(Of T)` range constructor.  It looks like a bug to me (not sure if it's in `Cast(Of T)` or `List(Of T)` but I'm pretty sure it's one of the two) as there is a call down to a helper function taking `ACTUATORMODELS[]` as an argument.  It looks like an erroneous optimization that thinks it can use a specialized array handling but misses that the array type might not be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's interesting that it stopped working. You can replace the code with a Select and cast to make it work

```vb
Dim retNumberList = {1, 2, 3, 4}
' either of these will produce a List of your Enum
Dim a = retNumberList.Select(Function(i) DirectCast(i, ACTUATORMODELS)).ToList()
Dim b = retNumberList.Select(Function(i) CType(i, ACTUATORMODELS)).ToList()
```

As for the original not working:

```vb
Dim c = retNumberList.Cast(Of ACTUATORMODELS)().ToList()
```

The literature suggests this is the equivalent of a `(type)obj` c# style cast, but both versions of vb.net cast work in the select. I am not sure why.

Comment: Thanks djv. Your code got me my list without the error.

Answer (score 2):

djv's answer helps fix your problem.  Hopefully this answer will explain what's going wrong.  If you look at the reference source for `Cast(Of T)` on an untyped `IEnumerable`, you'll find that the first thing that happens is the C# equivalent of this:

```vb
Dim asTyped = TryCast(source, IEnumerable(Of TResult))
If asTyped IsNot Nothing Then Return asTyped
```

Surprisingly, this cast will work for `Integer()` to `IEnumerable(Of ACTUATORMODELS)`.  This sets the issue in motion, because when it comes to making a `List(Of T)` out of the resulting sequence, it turns out that `Integer()` and `ACTUATORMODELS()` are actually not interchangeable, but `Cast` has already treated the sequence as though they are.

Based on some testing, this issue seems to arise out of the interaction of this corner case with a corner case in how the `List(Of T)` range constructor works and the more general corner case of `Integer()` vs `TEnum()`.

In the general case of iterating over `Integer()` as if it were `IEnumerable(Of TEnum)`, it works.  You can make a `For Each` loop over the sequence, the enumeration variable will have `TEnum` as the type, and you'll see the values as if they were `TEnum`.

The problem comes in the range constructor for `List(Of T)`, and an optimization there for a source that implements `ICollection(Of T)`.  In that case, the ctor will try to use `ICollection(Of T).CopyTo` to copy the items into the list's internal storage.  This is where the error ultimately occurs, because (going back to the implementation of `Cast(Of T)`) the source is still the `Integer()` array, and `Array.Copy` (via `Array.CopyTo`) is not OK with trying to do that with a destination of `TEnum()`.

I feel like this is a bug somewhere, though I'm not sure if it's in `Cast(Of T`), the `List(Of T)` range ctor, or in the array copy handling.  I'm also not sure it's something that will get fixed, since it's a corner case that hits what look like significant optimizations and would require a very specialized check to catch.